# Upgading to React Native 0.70 leads to Cycle in dependencies errors on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, cocoapods

After carefully following [the steps](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.2&to=0.70.0) from the React Native upgrade helper and upgrading to 0.70 I can't build neither from xcode nor with `yarn ios`. Getting an error:

`Cycle in dependencies between targets 'RNReanimated' and 'Pods-myproj'; building could produce unreliable results.`

I have tried various things, including disintegrating pods, cleaning the project / derived data, swapping old/new build systems and even removing the target dependencies manually in xcode, however the issue persists (in the last case it just shows a different cyclic dependency). Has anyone encountered this when upgrading to React Native 0.70?

Full text of the error:

```
Cycle in dependencies between targets 'RNReanimated' and 'Pods-myproj'; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: RNReanimated → myproj → Pods-myproj → RNReanimated
Cycle details:
→ Target 'RNReanimated': Libtool /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated/libRNReanimated.a normal
○ Target 'RNReanimated' has target dependency on Target 'FBReactNativeSpec'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'FBReactNativeSpec': script phase “[CP-User] Generate Specs”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'myproj': script phase “Bundle React Native code and images”
→ Target 'myproj' has target dependency on Target 'Pods-myproj'
→ Target 'Pods-myproj' has compile command with input '/Users/denyskniazhev/myproj/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myproj/Pods-myproj-dummy.m'


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated/libRNReanimated.a ->

command: target-RNReanimated-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd4253784ff6d1a0a1acaedc06a9f9e94921-:Debug:Libtool /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated/libRNReanimated.a normal ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnimatedSensorModule.o ->

command: target-RNReanimated-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd4253784ff6d1a0a1acaedc06a9f9e94921-:Debug:CompileC /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnimatedSensorModule.o /Users/denyskniazhev/myproj/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/AnimatedSensor/AnimatedSensorModule.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler ->

node: <target-RNReanimated-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd4253784ff6d1a0a1acaedc06a9f9e94921--begin-compiling> ->

command: Gate target-RNReanimated-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd4253784ff6d1a0a1acaedc06a9f9e94921--begin-compiling ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: <target-FBReactNativeSpec-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42d8e73feadee6a8e5c14524fc300acaed--modules-ready> ->

command: Gate target-FBReactNativeSpec-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42d8e73feadee6a8e5c14524fc300acaed--modules-ready ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/DerivedSources/codegen-FBReactNativeSpec.log ->

command: target-FBReactNativeSpec-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42d8e73feadee6a8e5c14524fc300acaed-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User] Generate Specs /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00024690.sh ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/myproj/ios/.xcode.env.local/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: 2 ->

directoryContents: /Users/denyskniazhev/myproj/ios/.xcode.env.local ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/myproj/ios/.xcode.env.local ->

command: target-myproj-31124c55eae76d2f6224153cd522b4b97ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Bundle React Native code and images /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh ->

command: target-myproj-31124c55eae76d2f6224153cd522b4b97ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh ->

node: <target-myproj-31124c55eae76d2f6224153cd522b4b97ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--entry> ->

command: Gate target-myproj-31124c55eae76d2f6224153cd522b4b97ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--entry ->

node: <target-Pods-myproj-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd427e062cc62f6a1d52d742a11ac20f0458--end> ->

command: Gate target-Pods-myproj-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd427e062cc62f6a1d52d742a11ac20f0458--end ->

node: /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-myproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods-myproj-dummy.o ->

command: target-Pods-myproj-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd427e062cc62f6a1d52d742a11ac20f0458-:Debug:CompileC /Users/denyskniazhev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-chxzpwxxfrrttoddglozfoottfdh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-myproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods-myproj-dummy.o /Users/denyskniazhev/myproj/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myproj/Pods-myproj-dummy.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler ->

node: <target-Pods-myproj-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd427e062cc62f6a1d52d742a11ac20f0458--begin-compiling> ->

command: Gate target-Pods-myproj-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd427e062cc62f6a1d52d742a11ac20f0458--begin-compiling ->

node: <target-FBReactNativeSpec-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42d8e73feadee6a8e5c14524fc300acaed--modules-ready>
```

I have opened a [ticket](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34638) but there's no activity on it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to check my `project.pbxproj` file agains the [RN template](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.71.0-rc.3/template/ios/HelloWorld.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj) project. While I was upgrading the RN version I added by mistake:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/.xcode.env.local",
"$(SRCROOT)/.xcode.env",
```

to `outputPaths` instead of `inputPaths`

Answer (score 0):

Try this with above or latest version of React Native

npx react-native-asset